# Attoparsec: Skip rest of current line

Tags: haskell, attoparsec

I'm writing a parser using [attoparsec](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec). The parser is parsing a line-based format, for example this file

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
```

Let's assume the parser is currently placed just before `2` in the first line. How can I skip the rest of the line *including* the `\n` character.

*Note:* This question was answered Q&A-style and therefore intentionally doesn't show research effort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to this is a simple combinator, however I wasn't able to find an easy & ready-to-use solution for this.

```
import Data.Attoparsec.ByteString.Char8

skipRestOfLine :: Parser ()
skipRestOfLine = skipWhile (not . isEndOfLine) >> endOfLine
```